# Which is the best way to show another window in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi I got some problem with navigating windows in wpf mvvm. I got two wpf windows, let's say viewA and viewB. all respective view model are bind to the view using prism `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` .

This is my view.

```
<Window x:Class="eBriefcase.WPF.Views.CaseHearing"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="CaseHearing" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

If I want to go to another view, I create new window and use show function in View Model.

```
ViewB vB_ = new ViewB();
vB_.Show();
```

when I press show another form button, another duplicate wpf window is open. How can I control it?
I just studied WPF for only 10 days. Is it the correct way of navigating between views?

Best Rgds,
df

Comment: Look for Messaging mechanism in MVVM.

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I control it?"  And what does your Show() method look like?

Comment: To control not to open duplicate window.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question:

> I create new window and use show function

So the new window is shown.
You are being confused with the term `view`. View is not some kind of object in WPF. It's just logical part of MVVM concepts. 
Objects that you operate are `Windows`, `controls` and `pages`. 
Looks like you want to use WPF `pages` as different `views` of your data.
There are plenty of manuals on the net about WPF `pages` and `NavigationService` 
These are keywords that you need.

BTW, answering the question in the header: The best method to open windows is to wrap opening windows into some generic `WindowManager` and use

`new WindowType(){ DataContext = VM }.Show()`

Comment: I want to use WPF windows. is it the same ?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by 'use' and by 'WPF windows'. What do you want to achieve?